# How to get the name of a selected Object Python Maya

Tags: python, selection, maya, ls

Hei all,
I have this procedural program that creates different object in Maya through Python. After the creation of these elements I want to get the user the possibility to select some of these object and though a button to delete it...The problem is that I don't understand how to get the name of the object...
So far my code is this..

```
#Deletes Selected Element selected from the user
def DeleteSelection(*args):
    selected = cmds.ls(sl=1,sn=True)
    print(selected)
    #if(cmds.objExists()):
        #cmds.delete(selected)
```

#

And in the GUI I have this button...

```
cmds.button(label='Delete Selection', w=150,h=30,command=DeleteSelection)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cmds.ls will return a list, you need to check the list and delete what ever you want to delete, and sn is very bad always use long name because there can be duplicates.

```
selected = cmds.ls(sl=True,long=True) or []
for eachSel in selected:
   cmds.delete(eachSel)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
What's doc?

Comment: Oh i know the Maya page...It's simply that since I tried I wasn't able to work it out...But ok, I'll try more the next time :)

Comment: also this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/maya/7564/finding-scene-objects#t=201703251839167615943